# Xcode debug log only shows (lldb)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've searched for related questions, but still cannot found answer.
I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 + OSX 10.9.4 Mavericks to develop iOS Apps.

I don't know when it started, When there is a crash happens in my app, Xcode debug log only shows "(lldb)"
And no more logs, I've tried to type "bt", but the log still can't help me debug.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BamG9Pl.png]

As the image shows

And the reason of this crash, is I'm trying to store a Nil object into a NSArray, So it crashes.
In my memory, I remember that if trying to store Nil object into NSArray, it will show log like
"...object cannot be nil"

What happen to my Xcode? or this is normal?
Thank youZ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is normal. But it will crash only when you try to access it.